# SSRS (swtich or average or any formula)

Tags: reporting-services

I have a picture below that describes my problem. I want to add an average function at the FINAL GRADE and convert it to letter grade (LG) and grade point (GP). Only the column Qtr1,2,3 &4 are part of the SQL server db. I only created a column FINAL GRADE at the SSRS. I need also to populate the result at the GPA row. Hope somebody can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

[image: [enter image description here][2].com/7DMR3.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom code in your RDL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx).

You can write something like this.

```
public string ConvertGradetoLetterGrade(int grade)
{
   if (grade > 50)
      return "LG"
   else
      return "GP"

}

public decimal GetAverage(decimal qtr1, decimal qtr2, decimal qtr3, , decimal qtr4)
{
   decimal sumAll = qtr1+qtr2+qtr3+qtr4;
   return sumAll/4;
}
```

Then just call the name of the function in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is for your dataset to supply rows, not columns.  For example, this:

```
Subject - Quarter - Score
-------------------------
Math - Q1 - 65
Math - Q2 - 72
Science - Q1 - 80
Science - Q2 - 94
...
```

Your tablix can then use **column groups**, grouping on the Quarter field, and **row groups** grouping on the Subject field.  Lastly, you'd insert an additional column group, grouping on the static value 1, which would let you do the following:

```
=SUM(Fields!Score.Value) / 4
```

Which would be the mean average of all 4 quarter scores.  (Your field names may be different, of course).  If you want a different averaging method, you can use whatever you like.

The benefit to using a **column group** is that the same calculation will work both in the detail rows (Subject 1, Subject 2, ... , Subject N) and the total at the bottom for the GPA.  You can of course use different calculations as needed, as well.

Lastly, for the letter grade versions, a custom function, a simple lookup, or a bit of math and the Choose() function (good example here http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/6/decision-functions-in-ssrs.html) can do the trick.